# Create dmp files in release build

Tags: c++, windows, crash-dumps

how can I create dmp files when a program crash in release build? I think I should trigger the exceptions but I don't know how

Comment: What platform?  The C++ standard doesn't cover crash dumps, you need OS-specific mechanisms for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows you can use the Debug Helper API to write a minidump file to any location you choose.  This file does not need to be sent to Microsoft.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680369(v=vs.85).aspx

As others have mentioned, the dump file will be useless without PDB files from the correct build.  You may want to consider using Microsoft's symbol server to index and manage the PDB files.

You may also want to use Breakpad to report client errors directly to you:

http://code.google.com/p/google-breakpad/

Comment: How could i trigger all the exceptions? I saw that for use MiniDumpWriteDump i should check the code with try-except blocks

Comment: There is no need to use try blocks unless the code can recover from the exception. Look at SetUnhandledExceptionFilter to register a custom method to write the dump file [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[Windows automatically generates a minidump](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee416349%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) whenever a program [throws](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/exceptions/) an unhandled exception (i.e. exception for which you do not have *catch* block).
Be sure to build pdb files (assuming you use Visual Studio) so you could debug the dmp files.

Comment: Does it build minidumps for an application running in release build on a client machine?

Comment: yes, it does but pdb files are not by default created for the release build

Comment: anyway it is hard to answer your question - I can't see what you build with, for what platform, what installations are on clients etc.
\

Comment: Please note that you don't get the .dmp files easily, they go straight to Microsoft.  You have to sign up to get access to dumps collected through WER.

Comment: I assumed he needs the file and clients will submit it to him directly with logs - not through MS - but the question is very vague.

Comment: I want to create minidump files when my application crash on a pc where is installed, the user will after decide if send it to me or not. I'm building the app for windows in C++ 2010